# Endpoint Information Gathering

Tags: windows

What would be the best tools to use to get information about a machine/endpoint. For example:

An endpoint was infected with a virus or malware, what would be the best way to get a historical snapshot of the machine (when it was provisioned, last updated, etc.)? I do not have physical access to the system. I don't want to run forensics on it, I just want to get as much information about the machine as possible.

Comment: Another thing I thought was to use either SMB (e.g., smbexec.py) or WMI (eg., wmiexec.py or wmidump -- http://www.cqure.net/wp/tools/network/wmidump/ ). You can find smbexec.py and wmiexec.py on Kali Linux in the `/usr/share/doc/python-impacket/examples/` directory

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, Linux, macOS with no previously-installed agents (e.g., either free or commercial agents such as SCCM, JAMF, osquery, [LimaCharlie](https://github.com/refractionPOINT/limacharlie), FireEye HX, Crowdstrike Falcon, et al), I would jump to either [GRR](https://github.com/google/grr) or NBD. For Windows, there is an [NBD-Server project](https://digiforensics.blogspot.com/2013/04/nbdserver.html) that can attach either memory (via GRR/Rekall's winpmem) as well as disks to NBD server TCP ports. For Unix and Linux OSes, it's simply nbd-server, available as a package on most distributions (or you can compile it to a specific platform).

The client should probably be a Linux machine and be able to load the NBD driver and use the [nbd-client](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/nbd-client.8.html) from userspace with The SleuthKit and filesystem mount tools. I have used CAINE Linux as the NBD client as it contains all of the tools necessary (N.B., others prefer SIFT, or via [GIFT](https://github.com/log2timeline/plaso/wiki/Ubuntu-Packaged-Release)). You can then use [plaso](https://github.com/log2timeline/plaso) to acquire artifacts. For a full list see the formats here -- https://github.com/log2timeline/plaso/wiki -- or check out the `--help` and `--info` flags for each of the plaso tools. One of the best ways to work cases and collaborate on timeline data is to use a tool such as Google [Timesketch](https://github.com/google/timesketch).

In a way, the above would be running forensics on it, but I still think it's the best way. If you want to run around networks for hunting operations, perhaps check out [Kansa](https://github.com/davehull/Kansa) or [PowerForensics](https://github.com/Invoke-IR/PowerForensics), but both of these are Windows-specific due to their reliance on PowerShell. CrowdStrike also has a wonderful free, open-source software (FOSS) solution, [Falcon Orchestrator](https://github.com/CrowdStrike/falcon-orchestrator), that is built for your purpose -- but again, only Windows-specific. The nicest thing about NBD, pmem, and plaso is that you only have to teach the concepts to your staff once and they apply equally-well to all platforms.

Comment: Have you used either GRR or Falcon Orchestrator? GRR looks interesting, but it says you have to add the agent to the machine you wish to collect information on. If I try to push an agent out to an infected endpoint, don't I risk the infection spreading?

Comment: Falcon, yes, but not the Ochestrator FOSS version. For GRR, there are specific ways to add additional security and obfuscation to the agent -- https://github.com/google/grr-doc/blob/master/admin.adoc#agent-protection -- fortunately, it's FOSS, so these can be easily added

Comment: To answer this for nbd-server -- at least on Linux, nbd-server can be run in userspace provided that it has access to the file-handle permissions necessary on the block device. One can also restrict it by source IP and/or require authentication for the nbd-client, although to encrypt you may need to wrap it with stunnel or similar. Typically, you could acquire this on a secured network, such as a hub, dedicated WLAN AP, or cross-over Ethernet